Not indexed by Bing
I registered my blog with Bing Webmaster Tools, but only the top page is indexed. Could you please advise on how to get other pages indexed?
The error message is as follows:

Blocked
The URL cannot appear on Bing
The inspected URL is recognized by Bing but cannot be offered to users
due to some issues. It is recommended to follow the Bing Webmaster
Guidelines.

By the way, it is correctly indexed by Google.

There is no way for us  to know what the issue is. Please see the following: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-bing/discovered-but-not-crawled-url-cannot-appear-on-bing/m-p/3280623

If it was open, I could have provided some insights.  Register with Yandex as well.  Bing and Yandex are stricter than Google.  And Yandex support are quite good in explaining what's wrong.  The best thing you can do is to find sites to test your site and fix everything they complain about.  Here's a list of what I found useful
